# Errors hidden with @ in php

Tags: php, debugging

I am repairing some old code that was made before me and I took about 2 hours to find a error because it was hidden by `@`.

Is that a way to deactivate this in PHP?

`display_errors` don't get errors hidden by `@`

Comment: `find ./ -name '*.php' -exec grep -Hn '@' {} \;` and then edit the files that are found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [`track_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.track-errors) to save whatever error was generated by the [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) (`@`) to a PHP variable. You can set `track_errors` in your php.ini file or use `ini_set`.

> If the track_errors feature is enabled, any error message generated by
> the expression will be saved in the variable `$php_errormsg`. This
> variable will be overwritten on each error, so check early if you want
> to use it.

### Example

```
<?php
ini_set('track_errors', true);
@strpos();
echo $php_errormsg;
```

Will output:

> strpos() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given

### Caveats

It is important to note that critical errors that cause the script to terminate that are suppressed by `@` will not be discoverable this way. In this case, if your script dies unexpectedly and without an error message, that should be a good indication to search for the `@` in your code.

> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable
> error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
> execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to
> suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available
> or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no
> indication as to why.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom error handler as described [in the php documentation for error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: Setting a custom error handler via `set_error_handler()` will return `0` when an error occurs on expressions preceded with a `@`. That can be helpful to indicate something wrong happened, but doesn't give any indication on what failed. I believe setting the `track_errors` flag would provide greater benefit into tracking down the exact errors.